# Google Maps Styled & Visualization GeoCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a styled google map and I want to use some visualization Geocharts. Can I use both simultaniously?

```
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var mateo = new google.maps.LatLng(37.53, -122.343);

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

var featureOpts = [...MY STYLE...];

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: mateo,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now, I also want to use Visualization, GeoCharts

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

I would ideally like to have my map style and another style setting for all the selected countries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both Maps and GeoCharts together - just include the javascript and HTML for both.  The Map and GeoChart styles and code won't interfere with one another (unless you want some interaction between the two, in which case there are ways to hook them together).

Edit in response to comments:

The GeoCharts and Maps can't be merged together into a single map; but the Maps API does support custom layers, which you can use to build a choropleth map using colored vector polygons, which should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I want them on the same graph. I.e. The features of Visualize GeoCharts with the style of Styled Maps. How do I hook them together?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  The GeoCharts and Maps don't support each other's features, so there isn't a built-in way to handle this.  The Maps API does support custom layers, which you can use to build a choropleth map (the GeoCharts are choropleth maps) using colored vector polygons.